# How to create Javascript Blackjack

Tags: javascript, html, blackjack

I'm having trouble creating a Blackjack program to display in an HTML page using an external Javascript file.

I don't need to label my cards, and I've created a dealer that will always be between 17-21 in score.

I'm unsure of what parts of my code is completely wrong and what needs a bit of tweaking. I believe I've done something that has broken the program.

**EDIT:** I've edited some of the fixes that many of you have helped with, an error I get when running the program is that if I do use an alert to display the score/outcome, the alert does not appear when running.

My goal is to display my the score/cards from my Javascript code into my HTML code which looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JavaScript Blackjack</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSSedit.css">

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Blackjack.js">
</script>

<h1>Javascript Blackjack</h1>

    <p>Player's Hand: </p>
        <br>
    <p>Dealer's Score: </p>
    <p>Player's Score: </p>
        <br>
    <p>Game Results: </p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

My javascript code:

```
//function that returns a random card
var deal = function() {
  card = Math.floor(Math.random()*52+1);
  return card;
};

//function that returns dealers hand between 17-21
var dealerhand = function(x, y) {
    cardDealer = Math.floor(Math.random()*(21 - 17 + 1)+17);
    return cardDealer;
}

//declaring variables
var card1 = deal();
var card2 = deal();
var dealer = dealerhand();
var x = 17;
var y = 21;

//retrieving the value of the cards from the deal function
var getValue = function(card) {

    if(card % 13 === 0 || card % 13 === 11 || card % 13 === 12){
        return 10;   
    }
    if(card % 13 === 1){
        return 11;   
    }
    else{
        return card % 13;
    }
}


//scoring the cards dealt and determining the outcome
//using the if and else if statements    
function score() {

    if ((getValue(card1) + getValue(card2)) > 22){
        return "Busted!";
    }
    else if (getValue(cardDealer) > getValue(card1) + getValue(card2)){
        return "You lose!";
    }
    else if (getValue(cardDealer) === getValue(card1) + getValue(card2)){
        return "Draw!";
    }
    else{
        return getValue(card1) + getValue(card2);
    }
}

//Need to display results onto HTML page        
//alert("You have card " + card1 + " / " + card2 +
//        " Score: " + score(card1, card2);
```

Comment: So what is the problem?  Are you getting an error or unexpected behaviour? Please update your question with what is happening when you run your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error on your deal function

```js
//function that returns dealers hand between 17-21
var dealerhand = function(17, 21) {
    card = Math.floor(Math.random()*(21 - 17 + 1)+17);
    return cardD; //should be return card;
}
```

Use the console in your browser (accessible through dev tools) to help spot errors in your application, errors like this show up bright as day.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error on line 14:

```
var dealerhand = function(17, 21) {
...
```

You can only pass variables as arguments to a function and 17 and 21 are not variables. An easy fix would be:

```
var a = 17;
var b = 21;
var dealerhand = function(a, b) {
...
```

Hopefully ES6's argument defaults will clear some confusion in this area.

Edit:

You have another error on line 41:

```
if (getValue(card1) + getValue(card2) > 22{
```

Should be

```
if ((getValue(card1) + getValue(card2)) > 22) { ... }
```

Edit 2:

An another one. Functions should be declared before using references in the variables and thus these two functions should come before your *declaring variables* comment.

```
// function that returns a random card
var deal = function() {
  card = Math.floor(Math.random()*52+1);
  return card;
};


// function that returns dealers hand between 17-21
var dealerhand = function(a, b) {
    card = Math.floor(Math.random()*(21 - 17 + 1)+17);
    return cardD;
}
```

Comment: So I must have variables declared after creating my functions?

Comment: I see, thank you! Otherwise, do you notice any other errors within my code? Or code that is missing within my Blackjack program?? I'm not as experienced to  actually spot these things.

Comment: I think you are good to go. Try your code using the dev console Ctrl+Shift+I on Chrome (lookup tutorials on that if you need to) and good luck! Upvote if you feel I answered your question.